# Dictionaries x.update(y) for pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am sitting in front of a probably very simple problem. I have two pandas DataFrames with some common Indices, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame(index=[1, 2, 3, 4],
                 data={'d': [5, 5, 5, 5]})
y = pd.DataFrame(index=[3, 4, 5, 6],
                 data={'d':  [6, 6, 6, 6]})
```

What i now want to do is to update `x` by `y`. This means to me three things:

1. The indices `1, 2` are only in `x` and not in `y`. Keep the values from `x`.
2. The indices `3, 4` are common indices in `x` and `y`. Update the values with the new info from `y`.
3. The indices `5, 6` are only in `y`. Add them with their respective values to `x`.

In total, the result should look like this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                 data={'d': [5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]})
```

Thinking in terms of python dictionaries, I tried `x.update(y)`, which did steps 1. and 2., but doesn't do step 3.
I am confident that this is a one-liner, but i just cannot find it.

### Addendum

I mentioned dictionaries (with the index as key), the approach there would look like this:

```
a = {1: 5,
     2: 5,
     3: 5,
     4: 5}

b = {3: 6,
     4: 6,
     5: 6,
     7: 6}

a.update(b)
```

It returns:

```
{1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 6, 5: 6, 7: 6}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `combine_first` but using y as the destination, this will overwrite the values from x that are missing from y:

```
In [75]:

y.combine_first(x)
Out[75]:
   d
1  5
2  5
3  6
4  6
5  6
6  6
```

you can't use [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update) to achieve what you want as this only updates the existing values:

```
In [79]:

x.update(y)
x
Out[79]:
   d
1  5
2  5
3  6
4  6
```

Comment: So easy! I expected something like this - one just has to get to know all the possibilities that pandas offers... Thanks!

Comment: One flaw: I would like to modify ``x`` by this operation and not ``y``. This can be done by: ``x = y.combine_first(x)``.

Comment: Yes you would need to overwrite x if that is your intention